# Block Android App to be sent

Tags: android, block

Is it possible to block sending of my app (.apk file) from the phone it is installed on to an other phone?  It will not appear in the market, i will install it manually.

Comment: Please clarify your questions. What do you mean by 'being sent to another phone'. When/how does this happen?

Comment: You want to prevent sharing of the .apk file?

Comment: Some file browsers can create backups from the app, wich you can send via bluetooth to other phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking whether it is possible to stop a user from doing stuff with the .APK application file then no, there is no full proof way. But you can make it more difficult for them.

[How to proect .apk file being shared with other people?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717580/how-to-proect-apk-file-being-shared-with-other-people)

Comment: If user has rooted phone, I don't see how you can prohibit him from making a copy of the apk using adb. How would you make it difficult for an user with a rooted phone to copy an .apk?

Comment: If you're dealing with rooted users, I think you're only option is some kind of centralized web-service. But even then, there are ways to get around it.

From the link I posted above:

If you do not do that, then you may, for example, require the application to talk to a centralized web-service that vets the phone ID against a list of authorized devices, allowing the application to run in this case (this is the FlexLM model).